# How to add a reload link for captcha?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, captcha

I've done some research on this matter but each php form differs to one another so other peoples solutions probably won't work for me.
I want to have a link that says "reload captcha" and when its clicked it reloads without refreshing the page.
My form does use AJAX and javascript and I'm guessing this is whats needed to get this right.

The javascript for my form goes like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('.contactform').submit(function() {
    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    var form = this;
    $('.submit', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').after(
          '<img src="assets/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />');
    $('.message', this).slideUp(750, function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $.post(action, {
            name: $('.name', form).val(),
            email: $('.email', form).val(),
            phone: $('.phone', form).val(),
            comments: $('.comments', form).val(),
            verify: $('.verify', form).val()
        },
        function(data) {
            $('.message', form).html(data);
            $('.message', form).slideDown('slow');
            $('img.loader', form).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
            $('.submit', form).removeAttr('disabled');
            if (data.match('success') != null)
            $('.message', form).show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
        });
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

PHP form goes like:

```
 <?php if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

 if(!$_POST) exit;

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");


$address = "email@domain.com";
$bcc = "email@domain.com";

    $twitter_active     = 0;
    $twitter_user       = ""; // Your user name
    $consumer_key       = "";
    $consumer_secret    = "";
    $token              = "";
    $secret             = "";

$name    = $_POST['name'];
$email  = $_POST['email'];
$phone  = $_POST['phone'];
$dayin  = $_POST['dayin'];
$dayout = $_POST['dayout'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

if (isset($_POST['verify'])) :
    $posted_verify   = $_POST['verify'];
    $posted_verify   = md5($posted_verify);
else :
    $posted_verify = '';
endif;

// Important Variables
$session_verify = $_SESSION['verify'];

if (empty($session_verify)) $session_verify = $_COOKIE['verify'];

$error = '';

    if(trim($name) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>Your name is required.</li>';
    }

    if(trim($email) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>Your e-mail address is required.</li>';
    } elseif(!isEmail($email)) {
        $error .= '<li>You have entered an invalid e-mail address.</li>';
    }

    if(trim($phone) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>Your phone number is required.</li>';
    } elseif(!is_numeric($phone)) {
        $error .= '<li>Your phone number can only contain digits (numbers 
 and no spaces).</li>';
    }

    if(trim($comments) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>You must enter a message to send.</li>';
    }

    if($session_verify != $posted_verify) {
        $error .= '<li>The verification code you entered is incorrect.
  </li>';
    }

    if($error != '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please correct the 
  errors below and try again.';
        echo '<ul class="error_messages">' . $error . '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';

    } else {

    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { $comments = stripslashes($comments); }

     $e_subject = 'Website Enquiry';
     $msg = '<html><body>    </body></html>';

    if($twitter_active == 1) {

        $twitter_msg = $name . " - " . $comments . ". You can contact " . 
  $name . " via email, " . $email ." or via phone " . $phone . ".";
        twittermessage($twitter_user, $twitter_msg, $consumer_key, 
  $consumer_secret, $token, $secret);

    }

    $msg = wordwrap( $msg, 70 );

    $headers = "From: $email\r\nBCC:{$bcc}\r\n" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'. "\n\r\n" . PHP_EOL;

    if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

     echo "<fieldset>";
     echo "<div id='success_page'>";
     echo "<img src='success.png' align='absmiddle' style='padding-right:5px;' 
 /><strong>Email Sent Successfully.</strong>";
     echo "</div>";
     echo "</fieldset>";

     } else {

     echo 'ERROR!'; // Dont Edit.

     }

}

 function twittermessage($user, $message, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $token, 
 $secret)     { // Twitter Direct Message function, do not edit.

require_once('twitter/EpiCurl.php');
require_once('twitter/EpiOAuth.php');
require_once('twitter/EpiTwitter.php');

$Twitter = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
$Twitter->setToken($token, $secret);

$direct_message = $Twitter->post_direct_messagesNew( array('user' => $user, 'text' 
=> $message) );
$tweet_info = $direct_message->responseText;

}

?>
```

(I took the email HTML in $msg out because it was too much code and I don't think it was necessary to include it)

The HTML for the captcha on my form goes like:

```
<label for="verify" accesskey="V">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="image.php" 
alt="Image verification" border="0"/></label>

<input name="verify" type="text" id="verify" class="verify" size="6" value="" 
style="width: 50px;" />
```

Anyone know what I should do on a step by step basis? (note: I am still an amateur at php and ajax) ... oh and no I don't want to use reCaptcha if you're thinking that :)

Comment: Your first sentence was promising about doing research but you lost me after the pages of PHP code. Try making a minimal test case or at the very least cutting out a huge chunk of irrelevant code (error logging, etc.) to assist us. Also, explain what approach got you closest and what's not working with it - Personally, I'm far more willing to solve a specific problem/bug than doing a piece of work in my spare time. The first is interesting, the second is just work. Of course, that's just my opinion.

Comment: What generates the Captcha image for you? Think of it this way... When the page loads, your server writes out an <img> tag that tells the user's browser to request the Captcha image. You you need your jQuery to request a new Captcha image, and then use jQuery to replace the original Captcha image with the new one.

Comment: I know you guys are out to help and I appreciate that a lot and I do try explain the best I can. The long php code above is my php processing form (that submits the enquiry) ... I put that code there just in case you guys needed to see it to understand how my form works. Usually I get told that I haven't included all the necessary code, so I'm getting in the habit of posting all relevant information (that I think is relevant).

Comment: @MonkeyWrench - makes perfect sense! Now for a amateur like myself to just thumb suck code and write it out to make it work is another story. lol. This is why I need your guys help.

Comment: Its always easier to break down the problem into smaller components. The feature you're trying to add is a perfect example of that, and you can teach yourself a lot by doing so. Create a test page, throw a <div> and an <img> on there, and try to use jQuery to switch the image when you click on the div. Easy to do, and there's tons of examples on the jQuery documentation site. You need to understand how the individual concepts work before you solve the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

this should give you a headstart, this asssums that image.php generates the image and updates the session/cookie variable. We update the image to include a cache busting string so that it should update the image and the session variable.

**HTML**

```
<button id="reloadCaptcha">Reload Captcha</button>
```

**CHANGE HTML**

```
<img id="captchaImage" src="image.php" alt="Image verification" border="0"/>
```

**JS**

```
$('button#reloadCaptcha').click(function() {
    $('img#captchaImage').attr('src', 'image.php?'+new Date().getTime());
});
```

Obviously untested but should give you a good start at implementing it.